# start in validRange not display fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

```
I have:
<div class="show-schedule"></div>
From date: <input id="start-at" type="date">
To date: <input id="end-at" type="date">

$('#start-at, #end-at').change(function(){
from_date = moment($('#start-at').val(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
to_date = moment($('#end-at').val(), "YYYY-MM-DD").add(1, 'days');
if (from_date._i.length == 0 && to_date._i.length == 0){
  $('.show-schedule').fullCalendar('option', 'validRange', {});
}
else if (from_date._i.length != 0 && to_date._i.length == 0){
  $('.show-schedule').fullCalendar('option',
    'validRange', {start: from_date});
}
else if (from_date._i.length == 0 && to_date._i.length != 0){
  $('.show-schedule').fullCalendar('option',
    'validRange', {end: to_date});
}
else {
  if (from_date < to_date){
    $('.show-schedule').fullCalendar('option',
      'validRange', {start: from_date, end: to_date});
  }
  else {
    $('#start-at').val('');
    $('#start-at').focus();
  }
}
```

});
For example:

this month is March, if I choose January or February, I will not show me January or February, forcing me to press the PREV button to display it! How do I show last month without pressing the PREV button? 
Or anyone have a way to filter from one day to another? Please help me!

I want to make a choice of time from date to date like : from date:  to date:  how to handle? Please help me! thankss!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "gotoDate" method:

```
$('#start-at').change(function() {
  var from_date = moment($('#start-at').val(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
  if (from_date.isValid()){
    $('.show-schedule').fullCalendar('gotoDate', from_date);
  }
});
```

This will move the calendar to the date specified, keeping the view type the same.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/gotoDate for more.

Comment: I want to make a choice of time from date to date like :
from date: <input id="start-at" type="date"> to date: <input id="end-at" type="date"> how to handle?
Please help me! thankss!!!

Comment: That wasn't your question, you have changed it. I answered your original question correctly. If you have a different question, start a new one, and roll back this one. Thanks.